# How do I set a Range Parameter on the web form that will be applied on the crystal report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have just recently created a WebForm which consists of 2 forms, the first form consists of just a button to redirect to the second form which then opens up the Crystal Report.

All this is working fine and properly but now I would want to insert a Parameter(filtering a range) on the first WebForm so that it would be applied directly onto the crystal report once I open it.

Any ideas of what code I need to include? Any help would be great.

EDIT:

```
        ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        cryRpt.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReportCustomerInfo.rpt"));
        CrystalReportCustomerinfo.ReportSource = cryRpt;

        ParameterFieldDefinitions FirstParameterFieldDefinitions;
        ParameterFieldDefinition FirstParameterFieldDefinition;
        ParameterValues FirstParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
        ParameterDiscreteValue FirstParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        FirstParameterDiscreteValue.Value = Txt1.Text;
        FirstParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
        FirstParameterFieldDefinition = FirstParameterFieldDefinitions["FromID"];
        FirstParameterValues = FirstParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;
        FirstParameterValues.Clear();
        FirstParameterValues.Add(FirstParameterDiscreteValue);
        ParameterFieldDefinitions SecondParameterFieldDefinitions;
        ParameterFieldDefinition SecondParameterFieldDefinition;
        ParameterValues SecondParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
        ParameterDiscreteValue SecondParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        SecondParameterDiscreteValue.Value = Txt2.Text;
        SecondParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
        SecondParameterFieldDefinition = SecondParameterFieldDefinitions["ToID"];
        SecondParameterValues = SecondParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;
        SecondParameterValues.Clear();
        SecondParameterValues.Add(SecondParameterDiscreteValue);
        FirstParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(FirstParameterValues);
        SecondParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(SecondParameterValues);
        CrystalReportCustomerinfo.ReportSource = cryRpt;
        CrystalReportCustomerinfo.RefreshReport(); 
    }
```

Comment: This is simple thing. Make two parameters in Crystal Report and pass value from C# code to Crystal report parameter. @Yuen oon

Comment: @NoorAllSafaet the thing is i dont know what 'C# code' to include into my form, do u mind helping me?

Comment: yes answering within few moment.

Comment: please check answer. @Yuen oon

Comment: @NoorAllSafaet i think we are not on the same page here, on my defaultviewer.aspx i have inserted -
two text box for the user to input the parameters, and one button so that the user can click onto the button which then leads them into opening the crystal report. What I would like to do is to connect the parameters the user have inputted into the text box directly into the crystal report.

Eg. range between "1"(inserted in textbox 1) and "5"(inserted in textbox 2), this would then directly be filtered in the crystal report when the user opens the report

Comment: You can pass parameter value and can take the value for parameter. @Yuen oon

Comment: @NoorAllSafaet do checkout my previous comment above if you can help me with my problem, thanks for ur help again so far

Comment: I just putted static parameter value. You can take parameter value from textbox. There is no problem. User will take input parameter value from defaultviewer.aspx page? @Yuen oon

Comment: @NoorAllSafaet I would like the user to input the parameter value from the defaultviewer.aspx page where when they open the report it is already been filtered by the value they have inputted

Comment: You will add parameter value from textbox if you have any condition or calculation then you can write them in Crystal report. @Yuen oon

Comment: If you want to use same parameter field in  defaultviewer.aspx then add two textbox and a button then reopen the report in same page same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

```
private void btnReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
        rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReportCustomerInfo.rpt"));
        ParameterFieldDefinitions FirstParameterFieldDefinitions;
        ParameterFieldDefinition FirstParameterFieldDefinition;
        ParameterValues FirstParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
        ParameterDiscreteValue FirstParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        FirstParameterDiscreteValue.Value = Convert.ToInt32(from.Text);
        FirstParameterFieldDefinitions = rpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
        FirstParameterFieldDefinition = FirstParameterFieldDefinitions["FromID"];
        FirstParameterValues = FirstParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;
        FirstParameterValues.Clear();
        FirstParameterValues.Add(FirstParameterDiscreteValue);
        ParameterFieldDefinitions SecondParameterFieldDefinitions;
        ParameterFieldDefinition SecondParameterFieldDefinition;
        ParameterValues SecondParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
        ParameterDiscreteValue SecondParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        SecondParameterDiscreteValue.Value = Convert.ToInt32(to.Text); ;
        SecondParameterFieldDefinitions = rpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
        SecondParameterFieldDefinition = SecondParameterFieldDefinitions["ToID"];
        SecondParameterValues = SecondParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;
        SecondParameterValues.Clear();
        SecondParameterValues.Add(SecondParameterDiscreteValue);
        FirstParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(FirstParameterValues);
        SecondParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(SecondParameterValues);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
}
```

Comment: hello @NoorAllSafeat, i have used this code but when i input my data into the textbox, it still doesnt get pass onto the crystal Report

Comment: @Yuen oon you should make parameter in Crystal Report and Crystal report parameter and Code Parameter name must match and value type should be same.

Comment: hi @NoorAllSafeat, i have added my current code into my original question, do u mind checking it and identify where is the problem?

Comment: sure thing, i have inputted my code for my btn_click above in my question

Comment: @Yuen oon Teamviewer?

Comment: @NoorAllSafeat, is there a way to personal msg u?

Comment: yes but you are not eligible for this features. Send me teamviewer id and password